# Is "Give the gift of safe travel" correct?

Tags: grammar

## Give the Gift of SAFE TRAVEL

I am putting together a Christmas card and there is some debate as to whether this is grammatically correct. My thoughts are, you don't say give the gift of travels so you wouldn't say give the gift of safe travels.

Comment: What wish are you attempting to convey? Are you hoping the recipient will be safe in their travels?

Comment: It is directed towards a travel agent, so we aren't wishing anyone a safe trip but more reminding them to give the gift of safe travel not just give the gift of travel.

Comment: Travel agents don't *give* anything- they sell holidays and journeys and moreover, they cannot influence the safety of the travels, so this really does not work well. "May all your clients travel safely" is the best I can come up with...

Comment: If you've purchased a trip for someone and you've arranged it with a travel agent who specializes in finding safe buses, safe hotels, safe aircraft etc, then maybe you can *give the gift of safe travel*

Comment: I'd avoid that phrase -altogether. Think of something else.

Comment: Are you selling seat belts or DWI test meters? Offering to be a designated driver?

Answer (score 1):

"The gift of safe travel" (singular) is idiomatic commercialese.

Give them the gift of .....

hair color that won't fade

tires that last 10K miles longer

white teeth

relief from painful itching

Almost anything can go in the blank.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot give the gift of safe travels. Only the gift of a wish of safe travels

EDIT:

When travel agents say "safe travels" they are wishing you safe travels. They are not giving you the gift of safe travels

Comment: Please explain your answer in full.